# Javascript form fields not clickable

Tags: javascript, focus, drag

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/xNHKP/6/ (not working in the fiddle for some reason which i dont get, but it works on my site - http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z )

What i want is that the contact form (click last menu item to make it appear) can be dragged, but when someone drags or clicks on the text fields, they do not gain focus and so you can't type in them. Ironically, it works on internet explorer.

So how can i make the fields gain focus when clicked on? I don't mind making them non-draggable.

Thanks

edit: code below (tried to keep it as simple as possible, including only the relevant stuff)

```
dragDrop = {
initialMouseX: undefined,
initialMouseY: undefined,
startX: undefined,
startY: undefined,
draggedObject: undefined,

initElement: function (element) {
    if (typeof element == 'string')
        element = document.getElementById(element);
    element.onmousedown = dragDrop.startDragMouse;
}}

<form id="contactForm" onSubmit="return sendMail();">
  <textarea id="message" rows="8"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  dragDrop.initElement(document.getElementById('contactForm'));
</script>
```

Comment: Always include the relevant markup and code **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: i tried to put together some code that i believe is relevant

Comment: PS: Your X stays where it is in FX12

Comment: @mplungjan yeah i know that, thanks for pointing it out anyway. i will fix it when i get done with the dragging problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems you're struggling with it, here's what would I do considering what you want :

- addEventlistener to your form, make it not bubble so if you click on an inner element it doesn't trigger.
- let every inner element live it's life like usual, don't try to add messy events on them.

If you *really want/need* the user to be able to drag the form by dragging on a label or something you should explicitely filter what are the draggable elements. Then you can go back to a bubbling event and filter out what's not draggable. If it's not draggable, don't do anything else than a return so you don't have trouble with text selection.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyFq6/4/)

Comment: I added basic drag functionnality to be clearer, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/yyFq6/4/
You'll have to tweak it a bit (calculate position relative to where mouse was clicked instead of just moving the element) but everything works fine, you can now focus and select text as you will :)

Comment: I just saw this, oh wow. It works great, thanks so much! It's more than i ever hoped for. You have helped me a lot! Greetings from Albania :)

Comment: Hi again, im sorry to bother you again, but for some reason this is not working on my web site. I downloaded the latest version of jquery and added it in a script tag in my page, then copy/pasted your code. But it's not working. What could i be doing wrong? Never used jquery before btw...

Comment: I had some small error which i fixed. However, now with your code i can either drag the menu or the form. Can't drag them both. :(

Comment: Hey man, sorry I didn't catch your comment sooner. Well the code I gave you is intended for only one element. There's some more work to make it able to manage many dragable elements. I will post it here

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here is an answer : you just have to check that it's the form being dragged and not any other of it's inner elements so just edit your code like so :

```
dragDrop.startDragMouse = function(e) {
    dragDrop.startDrag(this);
    var evt = e || window.event;

    // Now check it's the correct element we're dealing with
    if(evt.target.id==="contactForm") {
        dragDrop.initialMouseX = evt.clientX;
        dragDrop.initialMouseY = evt.clientY;
        addEventSimple(document,'mousemove',dragDrop.dragMouse);
        addEventSimple(document,'mouseup',dragDrop.releaseElement);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, i still have to tweak it so it takes paragraphs and stuff within the form, but it works. I am wondering if i can make it drag AND focus on the text element? Cause ideally that's what i would like. Maybe write inside the same code a simple line to set focus on the clicked element?

Comment: \o/ Yay ! Well, if I was doing it, I would fire the focus event right after the mouse is down. Check [this link](http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly)

Comment: Basically, on a second thought, i think this may not be a good idea cause it may interfere with the person trying to mark text with his mouse within the text box.

Because there was much stuff in the form, i decided to whitelist for dragging everything bar the text elements.

There was though a small problem again, while the window (form element) was not draggable anymore, the text would still not gain focus. I solved this by adding an "else" to the if, giving focus to the clicked element. "if element is not one of these, drag it. else focus it"

Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Argh. The text is still not selectable with the mouse within the text box. But i will try to work this out!

Comment: It's not a good idea to mess up with focus and text selection, I think you did it right removing that feature. Consider using a draggable or an undraggable class so you can simply filter in/ou what you want. Doing so will save you lots of pain maintaining your black / white list. You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug I can see that as soon as you click on a form elemment it assigns a 'dragged' class to the form and when the mouse button is released the class is removed. You need to be assigning the 'dragged' class when the mouse button is pressed **and** the mouse is moved.

Comment: I am not sure that a class change is causing this. Why do you think it would work like that? Btw, the "dragged" class is empty.

Comment: I didn't say the class was causing it, I said your code was executing inappropriately (hence the class being assigned immediately when clicking on form elements)